# SMSPlugin is not working using cordova-2.2.js

Tags: android, cordova

SMSPlugin is not working on phonegap 2.2

how to send free sms using cordova phonegap 2.2

Comment: provide more details on the problem

Comment: this.ctx.getContext() is now obsolete for Cordova-2.2.js so in this SMSPlugin how to modify that part of code according to Cordova-2.2.js

Comment: private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
  SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
  
        PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.ctx.getContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);  
  
  manager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentIntent, null);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Change the this.ctx.getContext() to this.cordova.getActivity() and you should be okay.

Comment: can you please send me a SmsPlugin.zip file for Cordova-2.2.js

Comment: Can you please give me a guidance regarding how to convert plugin from phonegap version 1.9 to 2.2 which type of changes required some of i know like addConstructor method is depricated in phonegap version 2.2 in <plugin>.js file.thanks

Comment: Look at my post on the subject: http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/08/so-you-wanna-write-phonegap-200-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Working example plugin and app, works with Cordova 2.2.0 and Android 4.2:

https://github.com/DavidWalley/CordovaPlugin_AndroidSmsRead

Comment: I am getting an error like "Error getting inbox" and i am running this application on android 4.0 and Cordova 2.2

Comment: 12-20 17:44:26.271: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(27788): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
12-20 17:44:26.281: D/memalloc(27788): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53985000 size:4485120 offset:4239360 fd:102
12-20 17:44:26.291: D/memalloc(27788): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53dcc000 size:4730880 offset:4485120 fd:108
12-20 17:44:26.601: D/memalloc(27788): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x535fe000 size:1474560 offset:1228800 fd:111
12-20 17:44:26.721: D/memalloc(27788): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x53985000 size:4485120 offset:4239360

Comment: There is no error in logCat but it gives above output while deploying this application on actual device of android 4.0.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that.  Uses undocumented features, so perhaps things are different on different phones.  Tested on a Galaxy S2.

Comment: Application is giving same error on emulator also on button click at start up.Is there any additional specific settings are required for this application?